# INSERT INTO from multiple sources/tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, insert-select

I have a table `FinalTable` with these columns:

```
name, lastName, pesel, position, id_operator
```

I want to fill my `FinalTable` with values from 2 other tables:

- AAA - this table has columns like name, lastName, pesel, position
- BBB - this table has columns name, id_operator, pesel

I want to join `AAA` and `BBB` on the `pesel` column

```
insert into FinalTable (name, lastName, pesel, position, id_operator)
    select 
        name, lastName, pesel, position, 
        (select id_operator from BBB b where b.pesel = a.pesel) 
    from 
        AAA a;
```

How to do that? I'd like to set my last column `id_operator` to the value from `BBB`. The SQL query above is incorrect.

Comment: not sure if you're looking for join between two tables, or union all to have multiple selects. but try which ever fits your needs. EDIT: nvm, this is what you're looking for. http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-inner-join/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd insert a join query:

```
INSERT INTO FinalTable  (name, lastName, pesel, position, id_operator)
SELECT a.name, a.lastName, a.pesel, a.position, b.id_operator
FROM   AAA a
JOIN   BBB b ON pesel = a.pesel;
```

Comment: I get the error: column reference name is ambiguous. Table BBB has 'name' column too.

Comment: @Matley you could fully qualify all the columns. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into FinalTable  (name, lastName, pesel, position, id_operator)
select name, lastName, pesel, position, id_operator from AAA a join BBB b on a.pesel=b.pesel;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `join` between two tables

```
insert into FinalTable  (name, lastName, pesel, position, id_operator)
select name, lastName, pesel, position, id_operator    
from AAA a join BBB b on b.pesel = a.pesel
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a inner join

```
insert into FinalTable  (name, lastName, pesel, position, id_operator)
select  a.name, a.lastName, a.pesel, a.position, b.id_operator 
from AAA a
INNER JOIN BBB b ON  b.pesel = a.pesel 
;
```